# Обеспечение безопасности ввода данных

Tags: javascript, jquery, c#, asp.net-mvc

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые форумчане.
Подскажите с таким вопросом. Делаю маленький сайт с возможностью добавления новостей и в качестве текстового редактора подключаю Tinymce. При первом подключении выдало ошибку "Обнаружено потенциально опасное значение Request.Form, полученное от клиента", по данному вопросу чуть покопал форумы где рекомендуется вносить изменения в web.config и т.д., но в итоге использовал следующий атрибут:

```
 [UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml].
```

Вроде все работает все добавляет:). Вопрос вот в чем:
Насколько я понимаю все способы разрешающие вводить текст с HTML разметкой это обход безопасности? и все бы ничего пока добавления идут сугубо администратором сайта...но как решить вопрос безопасности в случае разрешения обычным пользователям вводить статьи? и чем может грозить ввод каких либо java script или какого другого кода?
За ранее спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Ввод данных ничем грозить не может. Проблема обычно в выводе ранее введенного текста - возможность вписать что угодно в текст страницы - это огромная дыра в безопасности.

Защита в виде Request.Form сделана прежде всего чтобы пресечь проблему на корню - раз текст нельзя просто ввести - его нельзя будет и вывести. Этот механизим валидации был самым простым в реализации. Сейчас его дополняет защита в виде необходимости явного вызова `Html.Raw` для вывода текста как html при рендеринге страницы. Но до MVC 4 разработчикам самим приходилось явно делать Encode при выводе html, так что предварительная проверка была совсем не лишней.